# ClassCastException.Communicate between Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, classcastexception

I want to pass a string from one fragment to other. I did next

1) Create interface

```
public interface Communicator {
public void respond(String data); }
```

2) In BakeFragment(fragment from where I pass variable)
I create

```
public class BakeFragment extends Fragment {... 
Communicator mCallBack;
```

then in alertdialog i pass myString
...

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Заказать", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    orderList.add(myString);
                    mCallBack.respond(myString);
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Вы выбрали "+myString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }); 
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mCallBack = (Communicator) getActivity();
}  ...}
```

3) I get this string in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator{  ... 
 @Override
public void respond(String data) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    OrderFragment f2 =(OrderFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
    f2.changeData(data);
}   ....}
```

4)Then i get string from MainActivity and pass to OrderFragment

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {...
public void changeData(String data){
         finalOrderList.add(data);

 } ...}
```

[image: When i add item]

[image: I get this list]

[image: But when i go to order list it's empty]

1) I add an item.
2) When i added an item i get this list(screen2)
3) When i go to orderlist, it is empty

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator{
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();



    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[11], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(11, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {


        displayView(11);
    }

}

@Override
public void respond(String data) {
    for(int i = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        String tag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();
        OrderFragment fragment;
        fragment=(OrderFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        if(fragment instanceof OrderFragment) {
            fragment.changeData(data);
            break;
        }

    }


}


/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
          return true;
        default:
          displayView(11);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RasRas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new BakeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new GarnishFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new HotDishesFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new DesertsFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new SnacksFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new DrinkFragment();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new PizzaFragment();
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new SaladFragment();
            break;
        case 9:
            fragment = new ConfectionFragment();
            break;
        case 10:
            fragment = new SoupFragment();
            break;
        case 11:
            fragment = new OrderFragment();
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}}
```

Comment: My guess is that when you call `findFragmentById`, the frame_container has an instance of BakeFragment and not OrderFragment, thus you get CassCastException. Why don't you try to add your string to a bundle and use that to pass a string from one fragment to another?

Comment: if i right understand you mean set/get arguments. I tried to do with bundle, but i get nullpointerexception, when i want to getArguments

Answer (score 1):

Log says it all. You are casting `BakeFragment` type to `OrderFragment`. I would suggest to identify type of fragment based on String data you get as param:

```
@Override
public void respond(String data) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    if( <CheckdataForFragmentType> )
    {
        // if data maps to OrderFragment type
        OrderFragment f2 =(OrderFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
        f2.changeData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I make next
    
    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {
        OrderFragment f2 = new OrderFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, f2).commit();
        f2.changeData(data);
    }

 and i get nullpointer exception at OrderFragment 
    finalOrderList.add(data);

Comment: Seems like finalOrderList is `null`. Can you please check that?

Comment: in OnCreate  I make finalOrderList = new ArrayList<String>();  but problem stil exists

Comment: i add finalOrderList = new ArrayList<String>();  to changeData(). Updated

Comment: Make `finalOrderList` a class member and then create it inside onCreateView of fragment

Comment: public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> finalOrderList= new ArrayList<>(); ...  Nothing changed

Comment: Can you do the creation part in onCreateView?

Comment: It's strange. when i add a dish from bakefragment, opened a list with selected item, but my target is another. I want to add some dishes(plenty! ), and then then i go to orderFragment, see all of it

Comment: Hmm. Looks like your ListView is getting messy.

Comment: I mean, I wish I could choose any dish, and then after I pressed the button order, the alert dialog box disappears, and I could even choose other dishes. And then, when I go into a orderList, all the dishes that i chose  were in this orderList

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have OrderFragment and BakeFragment added to your frame_container container. So, to avoid ClassCastException use the following code:

`for(int i = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    String tag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();
                    Fragment fragment =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
                    if(fragment instanceof OrderFragment) {
                        f2.changeData(data);
                        break;
                    }
             }`

Note: For this to work you need to set tag to your fragmnet when you are adding fragment to Activity by calling `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frame_container , mFragment, "bakefragment").addToBackStack("bakefragment").commit();`

Comment: i can't use getSupportFragmentManager. My MainActivity extends from AppCompatActivity. And i get incompatible types...

Comment: Then call getFragmentManager() instead

Comment: Fragment fragment =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag); if i use Fragment, i don't have access to changeData

Comment: Then use getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

Comment: public void respond(String data) {
        for(int i = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String tag = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();
            OrderFragment fragment;
            fragment=(OrderFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            if(fragment instanceof OrderFragment) {
                fragment.changeData(data);       break;
}}

Comment: But when i go to my orderlist, it's empty

Comment: how you are adding fragment to Activity? Code please